# Simple, JQUERY: How can i show a popup window on hyperlink click?

Tags: jquery

My aspx markup is as

```
<div class="sm08" id="dialog" title="Dialog Title"><asp:Literal ID="litTerms" runat="server"></asp:Literal></div>
```

and

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

How can i load the popup on hyperlink click?
Currently the popup is shown at page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }});
    });
  </script>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hp').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault() // prevents the default action of the anchor link
       $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }});
    })
});
```

Comment: Hello, Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a click listener to your link:

```
$('#hp').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#dialog').dialog('open'); 
});
```

Also, you will want to set 'autoOpen' to 'false:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }});
```